# How to give a new line instead of "," to LastIndexOf(",")?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
 this.lblmsg.Text = name.Remove(name.LastIndexOf(","));
```

The value displayed is in the form

> A,B,C

I need value as

> A
>
> B
>
> C

When i changed the code it shows an error.

```
this.lblmsg.Text = name.Remove(name.LastIndexOf("\n"));
```

How i will fix it?

Comment: Why `jquery` tag? You can replace your `,` with `Environment.NewLine` with `string.Replace` by the way.

Comment: have you tried replace function ? like this.lblmsg.Text = name.replace(",","<br/>")

Comment: 1) What error do you get? 2) Are you using ASP.Net Webforms?

Comment: It is not clear what you're tring to do and what actually happens. What is the value of `name` and what is your desired string?

Comment: yes using asp.net c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's presume that `name` is `"A,B,C,"` and you want these things:

1. remove the last comma
2. split the items by comma
3. show each item in a separated line in the label

You can do that with `String.Split` and `String.Join`:

```
String[] tokens = name.Split(new[]{","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
this.lblmsg.Text = string.Join("<br />", tokens);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.lblmsg.Text = name.Replace(",", "<br />");
```

This will replace your commas with a break to display it in a new line